# dc.js v4.1.0 and d3 v6.1.1: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined; d is a MouseEvent

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

**Background**

We are using dc.js to display a scatter plot, but after upgrading dc.js to v4.1.0 and d3 to v.6.1.1, the tooltip is no longer displayed.

**Problem**

The tooltip fails here:

```
private tip(d: any) {
  console.log(d);
  const xPlace = this.polygons.features.find((f) => f.properties.label === d.key[2]);
}
```

The console displays an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined;
```

After upgrading, `d` seems to be:

```
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 790, screenY: 337, clientX: 790, clientY: 203, ...}
```

so obviously `d.key[2]` fails.

**Question**

Was there a breaking change that we somehow missed?

How should we resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693132/7106086) help? The parameters passed to the event listeners are different in v6.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for raising this. Yes, although we intended this to be a backward compatible change, the signatures of D3 event handlers do change under d3@6 so user code will need to change too. Perhaps we should add a 4.1 upgrade guide pointing to the D3 changes log.