# D3 Tooltip issues with displaying d on hover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

venturing into D3 territory and was trying to set up a simple bar graph with tooltips but it seems I am not getting access to the data that I am passing into the mouseover event:

```js
chart.on("mouseover", function(d){
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                    .text(d.name + " - " + d.calories + " cal");
      
    })
```

[Heres a codepen link](https://codepen.io/jpsephine/pen/QWEdpWN)

THanks for any answers as I am a bit flummoxed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
chart.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", function(event, d){ 
  return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .text(d.name + " - " + d.calories + " cal");
})
```

I see two mistakes:

1. When you assign `mouseover` event, you need to do it on each `rect`, not on `chart`. So `chart.selectAll("rect").on` part fixes it.
2. `mouseover` handler function's first argument is `event` not `data`. The second one is `data`. So you need to do `function(event, d)` instead of `function(d)`

Here is the updated example: https://codepen.io/cypark/pen/NWrdpzd

Comment: Thank you for that. Originally I did have your 1. correct but in an effort to sift out the issue I modified. But number 2 was the culprit. It's strange though, when I looked at some exampes out there, almost all had the handlers function as `function(d)`. See [link](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369) and [link](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_stacked_hover.html)

Comment: You're welcome! It's probably because of the version difference. Check this answer for more info: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693132/unable-to-get-node-datum-on-mouseover-in-d3-v6/63693424#63693424

Good luck!!!