# D3js version transition (v4 to v6). Changes in Event handeling?

Tags: d3.js, event-handling, versioning

I'm trying to transition an older script from d3 v4 to v6 to use some new features. Mostly everything goes well.

The data is organized into two Data-Sets:
`Promise.all([mapData, infoData]).then(function([mapData, infoData]){   ...`

The skript draws a map flawlessly, but the map has events for mouseovers on its areas where things don't go as as expected:

```js
// Same code used in v4 as in v6 script
svgMap.append("g")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(mapData.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("id", function(d) {
                return d.properties.GEN
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath().projection(projection))
            .attr("fill", "rgb(241, 244, 245)" )
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                console.log("d",d);             
                var currentItem = infoData.filter(function(item) {
                    console.log("item", item);
                    return item.RS === d.properties.RS;
                })[0];
                displayInfobox( currentItem );
            });
```

From the console logs, I know that the infoData is properly filtered and has its item. The difference between d3 v4 and v6 seems to be what is passed as `d` argument.
In v6 the argument is the actual MounseEvent, whereas in v4 it is the feature of the mapdata.

Sadly I only have found only an [migration guide from v5 to v6](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide) but not from v4 to v5.

My questions:

- What changed in the event handling there, and how do I pass over the feature-data properly here?
- Is there any Overview or Guide for the v4 to v5 transition I can use for reference?

Comment: There are no changes in the event handling with `selection.on()` between d3v4 and d3v5. So a migration from d3v5 to d3v6 should be sufficient in this regard. d3v6 changes the signature of the listener to `function(event,d)` instead of `function(d,i,nodes)` - the event itself instead of being in a global `d3.event` is now just the parameter `event`, `this` in the event listener is the same in all versions. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/7106086) may help. To be clear, you're looking to access the datum in the event listener and not the mouse event?

Comment: Yes indeed, im trying to access the data, like it was in v4, when no event was passed on. Your comment already solved the actual issue! If you'd like to post it as an answer I'd upvote and accept-anser it ^^