# d3.js in Angular - Property 'event' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Trying to create network graph with Angular 9 and d3.js by following the example in https://medium.com/netscape/visualizing-data-with-angular-and-d3-209dde784aeb

Versions installed are
"d3": "^6.2.0",  "@types/d3": "^6.1.0"

Getting the below error - Property 'event' does not exist on type

[image]

Checked other answers in SO but they are all related to version mismatch and I just got the latest version from d3.

Help please.

Comment: Did you manage to update this tutorials service file with the fix? e.g. d3.event.x to event.x does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.event` has been removed in version 6. See also the [change log](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-60):

> D3 now passes events directly to listeners, replacing the d3.event global and bringing D3 inline with vanilla JavaScript and most other frameworks

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/5015356) addresses very well how to access the `event` object now.