# d3.event undefined in force-directed graph : adapt from v4 to v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I followed the model found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/heybignick/3faf257bbbbc7743bb72310d03b86ee8).

I have put everything into a fiddle found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/xdp7Laq4/15/)

The force graph shows as expected but when I try to drag a point, I get the following error appearing on the line

`if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined
    at SVGCircleElement.dragstarted (?editor_console=true:244)
    at ot.call (d3.min.js:2)
    at e (d3.min.js:2)
    at SVGCircleElement.d (d3.min.js:2)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.min.js:2)
```

This has to do with the d3 version (The model uses d3 v4 and i'm using 6.1.1 in my code). How would one adapt this code for d3 v6 ?

Comment: The signature of the function passed to `selection/drag.on()` has changed - the first parameter is now the event itself and d3.event has been removed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693132/7106086).

Comment: that was in fact it thank you very much - if you want to post an answer that might help someone else.