# d3-xyzoom: Scroll(wheel) zoom throwing "d3-xyzoom.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of null" when used with webpack

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, zooming

I am using D3V4 with webpack and d3-xyzoom is throwing
`d3-xyzoom.js:83 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of null` when I use the wheel on my chart.

Following is the import section of code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'popper.js';
import '../../theme/bootstrap-enisyst.scss';
import 'jquery-ui';
import 'jquery-blockui';
import 'jquery-widget';
import 'jquery-mousewheel';
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
import * as Papa from 'papaparse';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3ScaleChromatic from 'd3-scale-chromatic';
import * as d3xyzoom from 'd3-xyzoom';
import { interpolate } from 'd3-interpolate';
import 'html2canvas';
import log from 'loglevel';
import './eniChartCommon.css';
import './styleEniChart.css';

Object.assign(d3, d3xyzoom);
Object.assign(d3, d3ScaleChromatic);
Object.assign(d3, interpolate);
```

Following is my package.json dependencies section:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.32",
   "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
   "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
   "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
   "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.1",
   "@octokit/rest": "^18.0.9",
   "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
   "bootstrap-table": "^1.18.0",
   "bowser": "^2.11.0",
   "d3": "4.2.2",
   "d3-interpolate": "^2.0.1",
   "d3-scale-chromatic": "^2.0.0",
   "d3-tip": "^0.9.1",
   "d3-transition": "^2.0.0",
   "d3-xyzoom": "^1.5.0",
   "diff": "^4.0.2",
   "diff2html": "^3.1.15",
   "fs": "0.0.1-security",
   "github-markdown-css": "^4.0.0",
   "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
   "jquery": "^3.5.1",
   "jquery-blockui": "^2.7.0",
   "jquery-mousewheel": "^3.1.13",
   "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
   "jquery-widget": "^0.1.8",
   "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
   "jsx": "^0.9.89",
   "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
   "leaflet-easybutton": "^2.4.0",
   "leaflet-fullscreen": "^1.0.2",
   "leaflet-zoombox": "^0.5.1",
   "license-checker": "^25.0.1",
   "loglevel": "^1.7.0",
   "offline-js": "^0.7.19",
   "papaparse": "^5.3.0",
   "popper.js": "^1.16.1"
 }
```

d3-xyzoom.js:83 is

```
  // Ignore right-click, since that should open the context menu.
  function defaultFilter() {
    return !d3Selection.event.button;
  }
```

I have tried several versions of `d3-zoom` thinking that might fix the problem but adding `d3-zoom` as a separate m, module always causes more problems. I have tried several versions of d3-xyzoom but had no success. I know it is an import issue, but I don't know the right combination of imports in order for zoom on scroll to work

Answer (score 0):

[Since version 4](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.0.0), d3.js has had a structure of micro packages, for modularity. If you install `d3`, you get everything, but you can also pick and choose. With regards to the versioning of these micro packages, I am fairly sure that `0.x` corresponds to v4, `1.x` to v5 and `2.x` to the newly release d3 v6.

That means that you have packages that are meant for d3 v6 installed *alongside* packages for d3 v4. Specifically, `d3-interpolate`, `d3-transition`, and `d3-scale-chromatic`. Consider downgrading these or removing them all together, since they should be included in the regular `d3` package.

[In d3 v6](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0), a massive change was released; `d3.event` was dropped. It changed several things, which are well-addressed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693132/5015356). This is probably why your code failed.

In short; `d3-transition` or some other package required `d3-selection`, which overrode the installed version of `d3-selection` to a version that no longer supported `d3.event`. `d3-xyzoom` still expects `d3.event` to exist. Removing these packages should resolve the issue.