# d3.mouse is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Upgraded d3 library and now getting an error for executing the following code

```
console.log(`\n${JSON.stringify(d3.mouse)}\n`);
const mouse = d3.mouse(this);
```

Getting

```
undefined

d3.mouse is not a function
```

And it is not defined anywhere. I went trough [d3 exports](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md) and this function is not really exported from anywhere.

Comment: d3.mouse was removed in d3v6, you should use `d3.pointer(event)` ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#pointer)) now, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/7106086) answer discusses changes to event listeners including d3.mouse/d3.pointer

Comment: Ahh, good to know. Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

d3.mouse was removed in d3v6, you should use d3.pointer(event)

Answer (score 1):

An example of using event is represented below:

```
let mousemove = function (event, d) {
        tooltip
            .html("Year: " + d.Year + " Sales: " + d.value + " M$")
            .style("left", (event.pageX + 30) + "px") 
            .style("top", (event.pageY) + "px")
    }
```

If each data point has the values of year and value, you can demonstrate them using the code above. Event has two attributes: event.pageX and evev.pageY. Try to sum the returned values, for example event.pageX +30 , so they are not going to be in the exact position that the mouse is on.