# Make something like paint with SVG and JS

Tags: javascript, svg, paint

I tried to make something like paint of Windows, with SVG and JS. It works well, but it has a bug. I can not describe that how is that. You should see it. But it seems when you're drawing a line, it jumps to another position! Can anyone help me please?

Here is the Code:

**Html:**

```
<div id="Test" >
<svg height="300" width="300"></svg>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var i=0;
var Sx;
var Sy;
var Show = false;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
document.getElementById('Test').onmousedown = function clickEvent(e) {
      var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      Sx = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
      Sy = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
      Show = true;
      
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmouseup = function clickEvent2(e) {
      rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      var Ex = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
      var Ey = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
      var TheLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
      TheLine.innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(TheLine);
      i++;
      var LineZ = document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i];
      Show = false;
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmouseleave = function clickEvent4(e) {
    Show = false;
    console.log(":(");
    i++;
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmousemove = function clickEvent3(e) {
    if (Show == true)
    {
        rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        Ex = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
        Ey = e.clientY - rect.top;
        
        var TheLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
      document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(TheLine);
      ///i++;
      ///console.log(Sx," ",Sy," ", Ex, " ", Ey);
      var LineZ = document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i];
      if (LineZ != undefined && Ex != 0 && Ey != 0 && Ex != 1 && Ey != 1){
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"x1", Sx);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"y1", Sy);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"x2", Ex);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"y2", Ey);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttribute("style","stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2;visibility:visible");
      }
    }
}
})
```

**Edit:**

I think the problem is "e.target.getBoundingClientRect"; Cause I've set the SVG's width to 300. But when the line had jumped, I looked for "rect.width" and saw that's 20! While it had to be 300!

Here is a Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qrL2mvea/1

And here is the full code on snippest:

```js
var i=0;
var Sx;
var Sy;
var Show = false;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
document.getElementById('Test').onmousedown = function clickEvent(e) {
      var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      Sx = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
      Sy = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
      Show = true;
      
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmouseup = function clickEvent2(e) {
      rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      var Ex = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
      var Ey = e.clientY - rect.top;  //y position within the element.
      var TheLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
      TheLine.innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(TheLine);
      i++;
      var LineZ = document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i];
      Show = false;
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmouseleave = function clickEvent4(e) {
    Show = false;
    console.log(":(");
    i++;
}
document.getElementById('Test').onmousemove = function clickEvent3(e) {
    if (Show == true)
    {
        rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        Ex = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
        Ey = e.clientY - rect.top;
        
        var TheLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");
      document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].appendChild(TheLine);
      ///i++;
      ///console.log(Sx," ",Sy," ", Ex, " ", Ey);
      var LineZ = document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i];
      if (LineZ != undefined && Ex != 0 && Ey != 0 && Ex != 1 && Ey != 1){
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"x1", Sx);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"y1", Sy);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"x2", Ex);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttributeNS(null,"y2", Ey);
      document.getElementsByTagName("line")[i].setAttribute("style","stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2;visibility:visible");
      }
    }
}
})
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
#Test
{
    border:2px dotted blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="Test" >
<svg height="300" width="300"></svg>
</div>
```

**Edit2:**
I tried to use JQuery's:

"*event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;*"

and "*event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;*",

but exactly the same happens :(

The funny part is that when I use *e.clientX* and *e.clientX* instead, it's better, but again it's not Ok :(

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem, ideally a runnable one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Comment: So problem solved?

Comment: No, I thought I know what was the problem. But I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H i again, I solved it! I used D3 (Version 5.9.2 in jsfiddle, and 5 from it's origirnal website).

Here is the new code:

**Html:**

```
<div id="Test" >
```

**CSS:**

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
}
#Test
{
    border:2px dotted blue;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
svg {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

line {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var line;

var vis = d3.select("div").append("svg") 
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .on("mousedown", mousedown)
    .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
    .on("mouseup", mouseup);

function mousedown() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line = vis.append("line")
        .attr("x1", m[0])
        .attr("y1", m[1])
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
    
    vis.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    line.attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
}

function mouseup() {
    vis.on("mousemove", null);
}
function mouseleave() {

 vis.on("mousemove", null);
 
}
```

And here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zsaeLokh/

***Tips:***

*"d3.mouse"* doesn't work in new versions of D3 anymore. Use V5.9.2 or less. If you use it, It'll give an error:

> d3.mouse is not a function

I read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134858/d3-mouse-is-not-a-function) that we can use *"d3.pointer(event)"* instead.

You can add Version 5 of that by adding this code to your html code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

You can add it Wherever you want. But remember to add the JS part *After* the div. Otherwise, it'll give you an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined

And at last, in

```
var vis = d3.select("div").append("svg")
```

You should remember to change the *div*, to the element's name. For Example, if it's a *span*, change it like this:

```
var vis = d3.select("span").append("svg")
```

Thanks, hope you can use it, Bye.

**Note:**

I didn't write the full code, I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9tr7w/360/) fiddle.