# I am getting a strange error when using the "mousover" listener with D3.js. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, json, api, d3.js, mouseover

I am getting this error when mousing over the circle SVGs in my browser window:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (app.js:35)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v6.min.js:2)"
```

I believe this has something to do with the 'n' parameter or the "mousover" component. When I console.log(n) or console.log(n[0]) in a callback function other than mousover's, the n seems to be recognized and doesn't throw an error.

my app.js:

```
    const canvas = d3.select(".canva");
    
    const svgWidth = "100%";
    const svgHeight = "100%";
    const api_url =
    
    "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.geojson";
    
    const svg = canvas
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", svgWidth)
        .attr("height", svgHeight);
    
    d3.json(api_url).then((data) => {
        //in this fn we put our data together
    
        const circle = svg
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.features)
            .enter() //enter
            .append("circle"); //append combo
    
        circle
            .attr(
                "cx",
                (d, i) => 40 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 110 * d.properties.mag)
            )
            .attr("cy", (d, i) => 40 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 200))
            .attr("r", (d, i) => d.properties.mag * 4)
            .attr("fill", "black") //default fill
            .attr("fill", (d, i, n) => d.properties.alert)
            .style("top", 150)
            .on("mouseover", function (d, i, n) {
                d3.select(n[i])
                    .transition()
                    .duration(100) //millisecs
                    .style("opacity", 0.7);
            });
    });
```

JSON from USGS API:

```
    {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "metadata": {
            "generated": 1607915888000,
            "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_month.geojson",
            "title": "USGS Significant Earthquakes, Past Month",
            "status": 200,
            "api": "1.10.3",
            "count": 9
        },
        "features": [
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.1,
                    "place": "25 km E of Yilan, Taiwan",
                    "time": 1607606398910,
                    "updated": 1607782466973,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000cpqz",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us7000cpqz.geojson",
                    "felt": 237,
                    "cdi": 5.5,
                    "mmi": 5.056,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 703,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "7000cpqz",
                    "ids": ",us7000cpqz,",
                    "sources": ",us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 0.51,
                    "rms": 0.74,
                    "gap": 18,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.1 - 25 km E of Yilan, Taiwan"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        122.0098,
                        24.7632,
                        73.17
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us7000cpqz"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.1,
                    "place": "114 km E of Iquique, Chile",
                    "time": 1607273262722,
                    "updated": 1607892153584,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000cnnz",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us7000cnnz.geojson",
                    "felt": 104,
                    "cdi": 6.4,
                    "mmi": 6.092,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 639,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "7000cnnz",
                    "ids": ",us7000cnnz,",
                    "sources": ",us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 0.704,
                    "rms": 1.01,
                    "gap": 31,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.1 - 114 km E of Iquique, Chile"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -69.0663,
                        -20.3662,
                        105
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us7000cnnz"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 3.62,
                    "place": "6km SSW of Warner Springs, CA",
                    "time": 1607267873130,
                    "updated": 1607887006984,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ci39486671",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ci39486671.geojson",
                    "felt": 2698,
                    "cdi": 4.2,
                    "mmi": 4.78,
                    "alert": null,
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 622,
                    "net": "ci",
                    "code": "39486671",
                    "ids": ",ci39486671,us7000cnnm,",
                    "sources": ",ci,us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,focal-mechanism,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,shakemap,",
                    "nst": 138,
                    "dmin": 0.04204,
                    "rms": 0.21,
                    "gap": 12,
                    "magType": "mw",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 3.6 - 6km SSW of Warner Springs, CA"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -116.6693333,
                        33.237,
                        9.2
                    ]
                },
                "id": "ci39486671"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 4.39,
                    "place": "13km W of Lakeport, CA",
                    "time": 1607267013260,
                    "updated": 1607887025531,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc73494405",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/nc73494405.geojson",
                    "felt": 1166,
                    "cdi": 4.8,
                    "mmi": 5.78,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 1,
                    "sig": 776,
                    "net": "nc",
                    "code": "73494405",
                    "ids": ",ew1607267013,at00qkxb5x,nc73494405,us7000cnnf,",
                    "sources": ",ew,at,nc,us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,focal-mechanism,impact-link,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,shake-alert,shakemap,",
                    "nst": 74,
                    "dmin": 0.0443,
                    "rms": 0.1,
                    "gap": 52,
                    "magType": "mw",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 4.4 - 13km W of Lakeport, CA"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -123.0671667,
                        39.0376667,
                        4.95
                    ]
                },
                "id": "nc73494405"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 3.79,
                    "place": "7km WSW of Aguanga, CA",
                    "time": 1607146889460,
                    "updated": 1607634140371,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/ci39485527",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ci39485527.geojson",
                    "felt": 2088,
                    "cdi": 4.3,
                    "mmi": 4.52,
                    "alert": null,
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 651,
                    "net": "ci",
                    "code": "39485527",
                    "ids": ",ci39485527,us7000cnbw,",
                    "sources": ",ci,us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,focal-mechanism,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,shakemap,",
                    "nst": 152,
                    "dmin": 0.08846,
                    "rms": 0.23,
                    "gap": 17,
                    "magType": "ml",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 3.8 - 7km WSW of Aguanga, CA"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -116.9311667,
                        33.4211667,
                        8.08
                    ]
                },
                "id": "ci39485527"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.4,
                    "place": "44 km ESE of Nikolski, Alaska",
                    "time": 1606839759884,
                    "updated": 1607877173556,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000clnv",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us7000clnv.geojson",
                    "felt": 9,
                    "cdi": 8.2,
                    "mmi": 7.312,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 1,
                    "sig": 638,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "7000clnv",
                    "ids": ",at00qko5hv,us7000clnv,ak020ffy8cqw,",
                    "sources": ",at,us,ak,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,impact-link,losspager,moment-tensor,oaf,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 0.633,
                    "rms": 0.82,
                    "gap": 61,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.4 - 44 km ESE of Nikolski, Alaska"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -168.2667,
                        52.7655,
                        23
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us7000clnv"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.3,
                    "place": "72 km W of San Antonio de los Cobres, Argentina",
                    "time": 1606776903900,
                    "updated": 1607037450381,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000clbs",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us7000clbs.geojson",
                    "felt": 18,
                    "cdi": 5,
                    "mmi": 4.05,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 620,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "7000clbs",
                    "ids": ",us7000clbs,",
                    "sources": ",us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 1.736,
                    "rms": 1.1,
                    "gap": 32,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.3 - 72 km W of San Antonio de los Cobres, Argentina"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -67.0203,
                        -24.3318,
                        189
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us7000clbs"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.4,
                    "place": "88 km SSE of Sovetskaya Gavan’, Russia",
                    "time": 1606776874601,
                    "updated": 1607038676174,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us7000clbu",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us7000clbu.geojson",
                    "felt": 1,
                    "cdi": 2,
                    "mmi": 1.951,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 630,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "7000clbu",
                    "ids": ",us7000clbu,",
                    "sources": ",us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 1.854,
                    "rms": 0.94,
                    "gap": 26,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.4 - 88 km SSE of Sovetskaya Gavan’, Russia"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        140.7971,
                        48.2521,
                        589
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us7000clbu"
            },
            {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "mag": 6.1,
                    "place": "101 km NW of Constitución, Chile",
                    "time": 1606006496420,
                    "updated": 1607143424100,
                    "tz": null,
                    "url": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us6000crcq",
                    "detail": "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/us6000crcq.geojson",
                    "felt": 231,
                    "cdi": 4.9,
                    "mmi": 4.218,
                    "alert": "green",
                    "status": "reviewed",
                    "tsunami": 0,
                    "sig": 686,
                    "net": "us",
                    "code": "6000crcq",
                    "ids": ",us6000crcq,",
                    "sources": ",us,",
                    "types": ",dyfi,ground-failure,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,",
                    "nst": null,
                    "dmin": 1.021,
                    "rms": 0.6,
                    "gap": 16,
                    "magType": "mww",
                    "type": "earthquake",
                    "title": "M 6.1 - 101 km NW of Constitución, Chile"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [
                        -73.0671,
                        -34.5982,
                        19.5
                    ]
                },
                "id": "us6000crcq"
            }
        ],
        "bbox": [
            -168.2667,
            -34.5982,
            4.95,
            140.7971,
            52.7655,
            589
        ]
    }
```

and index.html:

```
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <title>D3 Intro</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
            <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="canva"></div>
    
            <script src="app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In d3v6 the function passed to .on has a different signature. Instead of `.on("mouseover", function (d, i, n) {` it's `.on("mousever",function(event,d) {` - not sure if this is the source of your error at the moment, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693132/unable-to-get-node-datum-on-mouseover-in-d3-v6/63693424#63693424), if this is the source of your error, then d3v5 should work with this code.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Andrew Reid's comment, it *was* a version issue. I looked into that and replaced this code:

```
    .on("mouseover", function (d, i, n) {
        d3.select(n[i])
            .transition()
            .duration(100) //millisecs
            .style("opacity", 0.7);
    });
```

with this:

```
    .on("mouseover", function () {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(100) //millisecs
            .style("opacity", 0.7);
    });
```

This code now functions as expected.