# Updating d3 to v6.3.1 & Angular to v11.0.6: ERROR - event was not found in d3

Tags: angular, d3.js

After updating d3 to `v6.3.1` and Angular to latest `v11.0.6`, getting the following error while doing `ng build --prod`. Earlier with d3 `v5.4.0` and Angular `v6.0.3`, everything was working fine.

Error while `ng build --prod`:

```
"export 'event' was not found in 'd3'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1463:22)
    at hooks.finishModules.callAsync.err (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1258:10)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:53:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:672:17)
    at _done (eval at create (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:36:22)
    at _addModuleChain (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1185:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (<application-path>\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1097:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

It seems that `event` is being referred from the following code:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
// Save x,y cordinates on drag start.
this.originalX = d3.event.x;
this.originalY = d3.event.y;
d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
```

After googling a bit, someone suggested to install `@types/d3` and then try; but after installing it, Webstorm starts to throw error on the usage of `d3.event`.

**Has the API changed for accessing event via d3? Or something else is missing?**

Comment: d3v6 removed `d3.event`, the event is now passed directly to the listener: `.on("event", function(event,d) { this.originalX = event.x .... })`

Comment: @AndrewReid I have downgraded to v5 and still getting the same error.

Comment: You indicated that the code worked with d3v5.4, but it's not working with d3v5.16? There should be no changes that affect the shared code between those two. Is it possible to share a minimal example showing this not working? Also - to clarify, does the linked issue you posted answer your question? It seems unresolved still there as well.

Comment: Now downgraded to `v5.4.0` and error vanished.

Comment: I'll reopen then, but it might be easier to upgrade to v6 than find a breaking difference between 5.4 and 5.16 in your setup. If using d3v6, that error does result because d3.event was removed, as noted in the previously linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/7106086).