# D3 Zoom Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use a simple `d3.zoom` following simple tutorials as this but I always incur in the same error that I don't understand.

here is my code:

```js
  let svg = d3.select(".chart_container")
  .append("svg")

  let g = svg.append('g')
    .attr("transform", `translate(200px, 200px)`);

  var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
    .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

  //specify what to do when zoom event listener is triggered 
  function zoom_actions(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }

  //add zoom behaviour to the svg element 
  //same as svg.call(zoom_handler); 
  zoom_handler(g);
```

but I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined
```

is `d3.event` changed? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If using d3v6: d3.event is no more as of d3.v6. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693132/unable-to-get-node-datum-on-mouseover-in-d3-v6/63693424#63693424) - doesn't speak to d3.transform specifically, but the event is now passed to the handler as the first parameter: `zoom_actions(event) { event.transform... }`

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me in d3 version 7.3.0

```
 .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
    svg.attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this))
  }))
```

Comment: what is the object you are using `.call` on?

Comment: @MichaelHiggins I believe he is calling it on the SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I read here, D3 v6 doesnt support `d3.event`. I was able to load a d3 graph by installing D3 v5:

```
npm install d3@5.16.0 --save
```

or

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-FHsFVKQ/T1KWJDGSbrUhTJyS1ph3eRrxI228ND0EGaEp6v4a/vGwPWd3Dtd/+9cI7ccofZvl/wulICEurHN1pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```