# d3 why on mousehover field is undefined and d3.event is undefined too?

Tags: d3.js

Got this problem. Could you have a look?
https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/BaZYewv

```
          tooltip.html(d.area + "%")
         // .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 3) + "px")
         // .style("top", (d3.event.pageY +  5) + "px")
```

Comment: In D3 v6 the on function was modified see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63693424/7106086). You are using v4 code with v7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. First, you have the order of the parameters swapped in your event listener. The first parameter is the event and the second parameter is the datum. Second, rather than `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY`, you can use `event.pageX` and `event.pageY`.

Here's an example:

```
  .on("mouseover", (event, d) => {
    tooltip.style("opacity", .7)
        .style("left", (event.pageX + 3) + "px")
        .style("top", (event.pageY +  5) + "px")
        .html(d.area + "%");
  })
  .on("mouseout", (event, d) => {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
  })
```

Comment: thank you Dan. it's interesting i'll have to study why event should come first. And how does it work here https://codepen.io/marcods/pen/vPqXVg?editors=0110

Comment: As Andrew noted in his comment, you are using D3 version 7. The example that you linked to here is using D3 version 4.