# Hover on data point returns undefined in D3.js line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The problem lies here- `d[0]` and `d[1]` return `undefined`, but I don't know how to access the data.

I've tried `d.Wavelength` (name of column at `d[0]`) but that doesn't work. In the example (link below) `d.value` is used, but I need to access values at `d[0]` and `d[1]`.

```
  function m_over(data){
    ttip.datum(data)
        .style("visibility","visible")
        .text(function(d){
              return ("Wavelength: " + d[0] + ", Sample_1_Absorbance: " + d[1])
              })
  }

  function m_out(data){
    ttip.style("visibility","hidden");
  }

  function m_move(data){
    ttip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
  }

  svg.selectAll('circle_samp_1')
     .data(data_in_range)
     .enter()
     .append('circle')
     .attr('cx', (d) => xScale(d[0]))
     .attr('cy', (d) => yScale(d[1]))
     .attr('r', 7)
     .attr('fill', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)')
     .attr('stroke', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)')
     .attr('stroke-width', 1)
     .attr('class', 'points')
     .style('pointer-events', 'all')
     .on("mouseover",function (d){
        return m_over(d)
     })
     .on("mousemove", function (d) {
        return m_move(d)
     })
     .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        return m_out(d)
     });
```

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/interactivity_tooltip.html) example. This is a similar issue to [another example](https://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/d9f3cd0d926af7a5a1a8) I've tried to recreate, where the issue lies here. In this example, the code is d.date, so I tried adapting it as below (last line), and with `d0[0]` but that doesn't work.

```
  function mousemove() {
        var x0 = xScale.invert(d3.pointer(event, this)[0]),
        i = d3.bisect(data, x0, 1),
        d0 = xScale(data[i - 1]),
        d1 = xScale(data[i]),
        d = x0 - d0.Wavelength > d1.Wavelength - x0 ? d1 : d0;
```

Here is a screenshot of my graph:
[image]

If you would like to see my data, or the rest of the code, let me know and I'll add it in. Thank you in advance.

Comment: without seeing your data structure of "data_in_range" it's hard to know but try `console.log(d)` before you return in the text function to find out what the structure of `d` is this should let you know if the information is gettign through and how to get it

Comment: @TomP thank you- it returns a MouseEvent. Its ToElement attribute has a ```__data__``` array that contains the information I need. How do I access this better?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63693132/7106086) for how to get the datum for new versions of D3 as compared with older, useful if looking at examples using older versions of D3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to adjust your event listeners.

As an example, in the "mouseover" function, the first argument is the mouse event, and there is a second argument which is the data attached to the element that dispatched that event...

```
.on("mouseover",(event, d)=>{
      //check what we're passing to the m_over function
      console.log('data:', d); 
      m_over(d);
})
```

Here's a really simple example illustrating the concept
https://codepen.io/tomp/pen/wveRNmV

Comment: This works great. Thank you!